# Create custom tags/attributes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, custom-attribute

I need to create custom tags inside of HTML. From what I have read on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp), you can use `<!ATTLIST myattribute type CDATA>` to allow the document to remain valid. Would it be possible to add this tag in using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why yes, yes [you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements). In fact, they're a stable part of the [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) standard.

> Custom Elements is a capability for creating your own custom HTML
>   elements. They can have their own scripted behavior and CSS styling.
>   They are a part of web components, but can also be used by themselves.
>
> It may be unclear as to why the new custom elements capability was
>   created, as it was already possible to create a tag name like `<mytag>`
>   and style it with CSS, then use scripting to attach behaviors to it. 
>   An advantage that custom elements have are their lifecycle reactions,
>   which allow attaching behaviors to different parts of the new
>   element's "lifecycle." For example, a certain behavior can be attached
>   for when the element is inserted into the DOM ("connected"), and a
>   different behavior when it is removed from the DOM ("disconnected"),
>   or when its attributes change.

## Example

```js
// Create a class for the element
class XProduct extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // Create a shadow root
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    // Create a standard img element and set its attributes.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.alt = this.getAttribute('data-name');
    img.src = this.getAttribute('data-img');
    img.width = '150';
    img.height = '150';
    img.className = 'product-img';

    // Add the image to the shadow root.
    shadow.appendChild(img);

    // Add an event listener to the image.
    img.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.location = this.getAttribute('data-url');
    });

    // Create a link to the product.
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerText = this.getAttribute('data-name');
    link.href = this.getAttribute('data-url');
    link.className = 'product-name';

    // Add the link to the shadow root.
    shadow.appendChild(link);
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('x-product', XProduct);
```

```css
body {
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

x-product {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

x-product::slotted(.product-img) {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

x-product::slotted(.product-name) {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #08C;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.75em 0;
}
```

```html
If nothing appeared below, then your browser does not support Custom Elements yet.
<x-product data-name="Ruby" data-img="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4621/ruby.png" data-url="http://example.com/1"></x-product>
<x-product data-name="JavaScript" data-img="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4621/javascript.png" data-url="http://example.com/2"></x-product>
<x-product data-name="Python" data-img="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4621/python.png" data-url="http://example.com/3"></x-product>
```

Comment: As soon as I can see this demo in Firefox (w/o flags) I will push for it in production.

Comment: For Firefox you will need a polyfill for another few months. Edge will need the polyfill for longer.

Comment: [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-elements#introduction) has some pretty neat performant polyfills built in.